# Calling a controller from a view - Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How do you render the result of a controller from within a view...?

This is what I am currently doing, but as the view is directly called... it does not fetch the model from my controller. which is stupid.

```
public function ListAction()
{
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $this->userRepository = $sm->get('Application\Model\Concrete\TGUserRepository');

    $users = $this->userRepository->Users();

    $view = new ViewModel( array( "Users" => $users ) );

        $secondarySidebarView = new ViewModel(); // I don't really wanna do this, because I've already got an awesome controller set up for this which may as well be used to generate the model :S ?
        $secondarySidebarView->setTemplate('something/poo'); // This only gets the view and doesn't call the controller first :S

    $view->addChild($secondarySidebarView, 'something');
    return $view;
}
```

view:

```
<?php    
    foreach( $this->Users as $user )
    {
        echo $user->Email;
    }

    echo $this->something; // Works fine
    print_r( $this->something->Poos ); // Crashes because the controller hasn't been called to generate the Poos :(
```

What I want to do inside my view is something like this:

```
echo RenderFromController( "action", "controllername" );
```

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do here. Why does the view need access to the model? All data should be modeled and passed to.the view. Are you following the MVC pattern?

Comment: It's not for use in the view, but you can use the [forward controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-forward) to use your awesome action ;)

Comment: @gavin - The view does not need access to the model... the controller has access to the model, the view calls the controller which then gets what is required

Comment: @Jimmyt1988, it is indeed what ZF2 do. Your request go through the router that dispatch the request to the right action in the right controller and then render the view you are returning from your action and fetch it in the response object and finally returning the response. The good point is, ZF2 use strategies to render a View, this way you can use/customize different rendering strategy without changing the viewmodel according to your output (web, cli, ajax, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to make this happen:

```
public function listAction()
{

     $view = new ViewModel();
     $view->setTemplate('users.phtml');
     $poos = $this->forward()
                   ->dispatch('Foo\Controller', array('action' => 'action-name'));
     $view->addChild($poos, 'Poos');

     /* Add more variables to $view as needed */

     return $view;
}
```

in `users.phtml`:

```
<?php

    echo $this->poos; //Will output the result of Foo\Controller::action-name
```